# name of boundary control entity diagram

Tags: uml, analysis, rup, ecb-pattern

As you know we can show boundary, control and entity classes in analysis model; but I am not sure what is the name of this diagram? somewhere I saw it is "use case model", another where called it "object model",...
If any one knows the exact name of this diagram, I will be thankful to help me.

[please help, here is a sample of this diagram:](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/enterprise/ecb/ecb_files/image009.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/enterprise/ecb/ecb.htm&h=358&w=661&sz=19&tbnid=bvYxTYO5FR_IHM%3a&tbnh=68&tbnw=125&prev=/search?q=boundary%2bcontrol%2bentity%2bdiagram&tbm=isch&tbo=u&zoom=1&q=boundary%20control%20entity%20diagram&usg=__Gd14acpS1PyJ7bUNao2n6N2yvac=&docid=bU8mEKpEBB3kBM&sa=X&ei=RfeiUfqMMsPQOev_gbAM&sqi=2&ved=0CC8Q9QEwAQ&dur=528)
http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/enterprise/ecb/ecb_files/image009.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/enterprise/ecb/ecb.htm&h=358&w=661&sz=19&tbnid=bvYxTYO5FR_IHM:&tbnh=68&tbnw=125&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dboundary%2Bcontrol%2Bentity%2Bdiagram%26tbm%3Disch%26tbo%3Du&zoom=1&q=boundary+control+entity+diagram&usg=__Gd14acpS1PyJ7bUNao2n6N2yvac=&docid=bU8mEKpEBB3kBM&sa=X&ei=RfeiUfqMMsPQOev_gbAM&sqi=2&ved=0CC8Q9QEwAQ&dur=528

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robustness Diagram
here is the link:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsysarch/v11/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sa.oomethod.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_Ideal_Object_Diagram.html
another link is here:
http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/robustnessDiagram.htm